# How to edit python3.10 resources to include collections.abc in place of collections due to AttributeError no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Tags: python, numpy, collections, python-3.10

Trying to install some image editing software (face recognition type).
Ubuntu 18.04, python3.10 which took too much work to get it upgraded but was needed for the image software.

Getting the AttributeError when I install numpy and none of the online threads solve this for me.

Tried to install packages and the central issue seems to be python-numpy
When I try to install numpy I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

Various threads give solutions that have worked for people but I am not finding any simple solution to solve my packages.  In particular the wheel seems to import resources from a zip file.  I've unzipped /usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.zip that was listed in the log and edited pyparsing.py to import collections.abc NO LUCK THERE.

Tried editing various other files such as main.py and **init**.py no success either.

Is there a simple way maybe in the install with options to direct the build to include collections.abc, or even when I try to import numpy ?

This seems to be one of the ongoing frustrations with linux that various software packages upgrade or ubuntu upgrades and it is difficult to keep them compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a lot of SO threads dealing with this. Since I had problems with my last Ubuntu upgrade, I'm currently using the windows boot, and Anaconda.

Here:

```
In [591]: sys.version
Out[591]: '3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'

In [592]: np.__version__
Out[592]: '1.21.5'
```

Looking at collections:

```
In [594]: import collections

In [595]: collections.MutableMapping
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7972\1388547110.py:1: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
  collections.MutableMapping
Out[595]: collections.abc.MutableMapping

In [596]: collections.abc.MutableMapping
Out[596]: collections.abc.MutableMapping
```

So if a module tried to use `collections.MutableMapping` with your 3.10 it would encounter this error.  I assume common packages like `numpy` have made such an correction, but I don't know as of when.

I'm not an expert on these versions.  Mostly I use what ever Python version is easiest to install, make sure I have the latest `setup tools`, and then use its `pip3` to install the latest package versions.